# Correct placement of Sqlite files in iOS5

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, ios5

I'm running into some confusion about proper placement of sqlite files within an iOS5 iPhone/iPad directory structure. At issue is conforming to the iCloud Data Storage guidelines.

Is the following correct?

I have a system database file, that is read-only. So that is placed in /Library/Caches.
I have a user database file, that is read-write, and contains user generated changes. So that gets placed in /Documents.

TIA,

jb

Answer (score 3):

Yes but apple is being difficult about this issue right now. As long as the document store is "small" then they won't complain. YMMV

http://www.marco.org/2011/10/13/ios5-caches-cleaning

Official docs.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW4